# How to serialize this class to json by GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit2

I use gson and retrofit2 with GsonConverterFactory for HTTP requests. When I try serialize this class

```
public class EventWrapper {
@SerializedName("events")
@Expose
private List<? extends Event> events = null;

public List<? extends Event> getEvents() {
    return events;
}

public void setEvents(List<? extends Event> events) {
    this.events = events;
}

public EventWrapper(List<? extends Event> events) {
    this.events = events;
}
}
```

request body looks like

```
{
  "events": [
    {
    }
  ]
}
```

If used `List<EventBattery>` instead `List<? extends Event>` all ok and request body looks like

```
{
  "events": [
    {
      "type": 1,
      "level": 100
    },
    {
      "type": 2,
      "level": 99
    }
  ]
}
```

`EventBattery` extends `Event`

Comment: I tested it with retrofit 2.2.0 & gson 2.8.0 and it got serialized as expected. Which versions do you use?

Comment: Marcin Jedynak, Retrofit 2.4.0 and gson 2.8.2

Comment: Same. The bounded wildcard type of the list shouldn't be a problem, as gson determines the correct adapter at runtime, by inspecting the class of each element. Could you also provide the code for Event, EventBattery and some code where you actually create the EventWrapper? Also you run both of the examples with different arguments (I see one event vs two events) so maybe the problem lies somewhere there. Finally does your Event/EventBattery use a custom TypeAdapter/Serializer?